# Why there are irrational numbers?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I do not quite get it. Why can't we represent all real numbers as a sum of rational numbers? Why do we need irrational numbers?

For example,

- $\pi=3.14159265358\cdots=3+10^{-1}+4*10^{-2}+10^{-3}+5*10^{-4}+\cdots$
- $e=2.71828182846\cdots=2+7*10^{-1}+10^{-2}+8*10^{-3}+2*10^{-4}+\cdots$
- And so on

Comment: For completeness ;)

Comment: Those aren't sums, those are limits of sequences.

Comment: $\frac12$ is not a sum of integers, no matter how hard you try.

Comment: What is the last rational number in one of your sums?

Comment: @J.W.Perry Probably there is no last. Because the sum never terminates

Comment: @Kira Very good. Case in point. You cannot represent these numbers as sums of rationals as you do not even know what the last [
pick a big number] of rationals would look like.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You begin by asking a question "why can't we represent all reals as infinite sums of rationals?"  You *can* do so, therefore the question has a false premise and cannot be answered. Your second question "why do we need irrational numbers?" I simply don't understand. Why does *who* need irrationals to do *what*?  Try re-stating your questions more precisely.

Comment: Your title question is yet a third question: "why are there irrational numbers?" Irrational numbers are defined as those reals which are not a ratio of two integers. There *are* irrational numbers; asking *why* there are irrational numbers, I don't know how to answer. Why is there anything at all?

Comment: @EricLippert I meant to say "if we can represent all real numbers as a sum, why we do specify that this number is irrational and this one is not". For example, $3.1=3+10^{-1}=\dfrac{31}{10}$. We can do the same for all real numbers. That's my question. And I know I am missing things here that's why I would like to get some helps. Thanks.

Comment: That is much more clear. The answer to your question is: any *finite* sum of rationals is a rational, but that is *not* the case for the limit of an infinite sum.  More generally, get into your head now that *a property shared by every member of a set* and *a property of the limit of that set* need not be the same. Every one of your *finite* sums is rational, but the limit need not be. Accidentally treating set elements and limits as the same thing is the cause of a great many mathematical mistakes.

Answer (score 7):

You can represent any real number as some convergent sequence of rational numbers, as you do above. However, irrational numbers are those numbers that cannot be expressed as any *finite* such sequence. However long of a finite sequence of rational numbers approaching $\pi$ you have, there is a positive real number $\varepsilon$ such that the last term in the sequence is at least $\varepsilon$ away from $\pi$ (In particular, we can take the last term of the sequence, $t$, and take $\varepsilon = \frac{|\pi - t|}{2}$).

Answer (score 7):

For a long time people believed that the rational numbers were enough to perform any arithmetic operation we needed. It wasn't until 500 BC that the Pythagoreans started to become aware that the rational numbers were not quite sufficient.

For instance, the Pythagoreans tried to compute something that seemed benign. They wanted to find the length of the diagonal of a square with sides of unit length. We know now (by the Pythagorean theorem) that this should be the number we represent as $\sqrt{2}$. The Pythagoreans tried to find a rational number corresponding to this and came to a contradiction. It's said that the Pythagoreans were so upset that they drowned the person who discovered this. I have also heard speculation that this is why Greek mathematics was so focused on geometry, since this is something you can "see" and away from uncomfortable concepts like irrational numbers.

This was the first instance where irrational number started to seem necessary. The next big irrational number to come forward was the number $\pi$. This was in 350 BC, and the first to try to approximate this number was Archimedes. This is where the estimate 22/7 came from. He also had a better estimate than that, it escapes me at the moment. The Bible also estimates this as 3, when it describes a fountain in Solomon's temple. I think the proof of the irrationality of $\pi$ had to wait for Lambert in the 1700s.

Irrational numbers came about to solve problems that rational numbers were not up to the task to do. Early mathematicians resisted the concept, but they have been well accepted for the past millennium at least.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLZMZ-CT7YU&src_vid=TlY-Sh9Rzas&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_702816) is Archimedes' method of calculating the value of $\pi$.

Comment: @David thanks for the edit! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Some relevant definitions seem to be in order.

Real number: Any number on the continuous real line from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Integer: A real number which can be expressed without a fractional component.

Rational number: A number which can be expressed as a ratio of two integers. Note that integers themselves are rational, since we can express any integer $n$ as $\frac{n}{1}$.

Irrational number: A number which cannot be expressed as a ratio of two integers.

Now, in particular, in your question $k\cdot10^{-n}$ is $\textit{not}$ an integer where $k$ and $n$ are positive integers and $k$ is a digit between $1$ and $9$. These are instead just $\textit{rational}$ numbers since $k\cdot10^{-n}=\dfrac{k}{10^n}$, which is a ratio of integers.

[Upsettingly for Pythagoras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus), irrational numbers do exist. [Here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html) is the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not represent them as p/q with both p and q integers.  That is why they are called irrational numbers.  Not representable as p/q.  0.33333....is 1/3.  root 2 can not be written as p/q where p and q are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers that cannot be expressed rationally arise naturally as solutions of equations. The solution of $x^2=2$ & of $x(1-x)=1$, & any of an infinitude of specificable polynomial equations, *cannot* be expressed rationally. It can be proven *directly*, by a simple recipe, that **no** rational number can satisfy either of the two equations I have *particularly* cited; and the same can be proven similarly for the general case.

Moreover there is a class of numbers yet beyond this: the *transcendental* numbers, any of which can be shown to be *not* the solution of *any* polynomial equation comprising a finite number of terms having integer coefficients.